# How to call a particular screen in Tkinter using OOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scope

I'm trying to clean up my Tkinter code by putting it into classes but I'm not able to call a particular screen. When I was using just functions I was using `Something.place_forget()` everywhere to get the next page. All my widgets were defined in global scope thus that was necessary however I expected to be able to call the methods from the class in which I defined my widgets in their respective local scope.

```
tkinter imports[...]
from functools import partial

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("700x700")
pagenumber = 1


class Input:

    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

    def checkPage(self, page):
        global pagenumber
        pagenumber = page
        print(pagenumber)

    def mainscreen(self):
        global pagenumber
        button_input = Button(self.screen, text="Input", padx="50", pady="25", bg="lightgrey",
                              command=partial(self.checkPage, 2))
        [...]
        button_input.place(x="400", y="350")

    def infoPage(self):
        title_enter = Label(self.screen, text="Enter")
            [...]
        submit.place(x="290", y="420")

    def ingredientsPage(self):
        pass


inputscreen = Input(gui)

if pagenumber == 1:
    inputscreen.mainscreen()
elif pagenumber == 2:
    print("reached")
    inputscreen.infoPage()

gui.mainloop()
```

What I'm trying to do is check the page number (which gets updated inside the class) and use that do display its respective page. Although the `pagenumber` is getting updated fine it doesn't display the screen it's supposed to.

Comment: I think the `if/elif` blocks should be put inside `checkPage()` function.

Comment: @acw1668 My class is initialised in global scope. How can I call a class from inside a class ?

Comment: It is hard to tell as I don't have full picture of your code.  Also your posted code has only one class.

Comment: @acw1668 I only need 2 classes in all. Can you give me an example on how I can initialise the class from inside and call it with respect to tkinter.

Comment: Once again as I said it is hard to tell without full picture of your code.  If you have only two classes, why don't you update your code to include the other class so that we have [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @acw1668 The second class doesn’t exist yet. I want to complete this class first and mainScreen and infoPage are the 2 tkinter screens I want displayed when page number is 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: As I don't know exactly what you want, but you can try the code in [here](https://pastebin.com/578mKn5L).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is given by acw but I'm putting it here as he hasn't answered it directly on stackoverflow. Basically use the clear method then call your next class.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("700x700")

class Input:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen

    def checkPage(self, page):
        if page == 1:
            self.clear()
            self.mainscreen()
        elif page == 2:
            self.clear()
            self.infoPage()

    def clear(self):
        for widget in self.screen.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

    def mainscreen(self):
        button_input = Button(self.screen, text="InfoPage", padx="50", pady="25", bg="lightgrey",
                              command=partial(self.checkPage, 2))
        button_input.place(x="400", y="350")

    def infoPage(self):
        title_enter = Label(self.screen, text="Enter")
        title_enter.place(x="290", y="420")

        button_input = Button(self.screen, text="MainScreen", padx="50", pady="25", bg="lightgrey",
                              command=partial(self.checkPage, 1))
        button_input.place(x="200", y="150")

    def ingredientsPage(self):
        pass


inputscreen = Input(gui)
inputscreen.checkPage(1)
gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks good you are missing one thing a callback to actually updates the screen.

```py
def page_monitor():
    if pagenumber == 1:
        inputscreen.mainscreen()
    elif pagenumber == 2:
        print("reached")
        inputscreen.infoPage()
    gui.after(1000, page_monitor)

page_monitor()
```

I'm not sure this will work like you want more than likely you will still have to forget the widgets you do not want displayed. You could easily make a function in your class that forgets the placement of all widgets and call them in your inputscreen.infoPage() and inputscreen.mainscreen() methods. It doesn't hurt to call place_forget() on a widget that isn't place, so that is the easiest way to do it. I have never tested the performance.

```py
tkinter imports[...]
from functools import partial

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("700x700")
pagenumber = 1


class Input:
    def __init__(self, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.button_input = Button(self.screen, text="Input", padx="50", 
                                   pady="25", bg="lightgrey",
                                   command=partial(self.changePage, 2))
        self.title_enter = Label(self.screen, text="Enter")

    def changePage(self, page):
        global pagenumber
        pagenumber = page
        print(pagenumber)

    def forget_widgets()
        self.button_input.place_forget()
        self.title_enter.place_forget()

    def mainscreen(self):
        self.forget_widgets()
        self.button_input.place(x="400", y="350")

    def infoPage(self):
        self.forget_widgets()
        self.title_enter.place(x="290", y="420")


    def ingredientsPage(self):
        pass


inputscreen = Input(gui)

def page_monitor():
    if pagenumber == 1:
        inputscreen.mainscreen()
    elif pagenumber == 2:
        print("reached")
        inputscreen.infoPage()
    gui.after(1000, page_monitor)

page_monitor()
gui.mainloop()
```

If you want to make functions to just forget the last page variables you would just need to design the program to only flow predictably from page to page or create a global variable to track the last page you were on and update it whenever your page changes. I didn't run this code, so my apologies if there are any errors.